# Calculating Date in Java

Tags: java, string, date, math, format

Ok so I am trying to create a date in this format:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy");
```

I am having trouble calculating that date so that it gives me 1/1/13.

```
Date newdate = new Date (136199001);
String date = dateformat.format(newdate);
```

However I can't work out how to do it to get to my desired date. I know I am suppose to work it out from 01/01/70 but I am having trouble. The question : what is the formula to work the date out?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: `Date newdate = dateformat.parse("01-01-13");` ?

Comment: for 1/1/13 ,1356978600000 should be input check other way.. . . newdate.getTime(); for the newdate of 01-01-13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use calendar object for a specific date. It is much easier.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(2013, 0, 1); //1st january 2013
Date date = cal.getTime();
SimpleDateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy");
String dateStr = dateformat.format(date);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say that what you are looking for is this:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy").parse("1/1/13");
```